# Nesting Excel Score

Tags: excel, nested

For a project we are making an Excel file for the WK in Russia.
So I need the following things (if its possible only nesting):

TOTO: the home team wins = 1, away team wins = 2, its equal = 3

This is what I have right now for these:

```
IF(F5<H5;"2";IF(F5>H5;"1";IF(F5;"3";IF(H5;"3";""))))
```

This works but if I set the score 0-0 then I get 0 back in stead of 3.

Then the next one:
If they gambled that the home team score is correct they get 2 points,
If they gambled that the away team score is correct they get 2 points
If they gambled that the TOTO is correct: 5 points
If all is correct: 1 bonus point

What i mean with the second thing is if somebody says that the score is 2-1 and the game ends on 0-1 then i get 2 points (one for the TOTO and 1 point for the team that scored 0-1).

E.g. Belgium-Tunis (player1) on 2-1 with TOTO = 1. Game ends on 0-1. Player1 gets 2 points in total because he predict the goals of Tunis correct.

Last but not least:

IF the teams are going to the quarter finals,... are coming a few lines on it:
Country good: 10 points
European champ correct: 25 points
Total yellow: 20 points
TOtal red: 20 points.

Comment: The idea of stack overflow is to ask a single question per "question"! Could you be a bit more specific what exactly you'd like answered?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the formula you want for the first of your questions (the home team wins = 1, away team wins = 2, its equal = 3) is:

```
=IF(F5<H5,"2",IF(F5>H5,"1",IF(F5=H5,"3","")))
```

Not sure why you have the numbers in speech marks (have left as is in the above) you could have:

```
=IF(F5<H5,2,IF(F5>H5,1,IF(F5=H5,3,"")))
```

Which would probably be easier if you want to do any maths with the values.

It's not entirely clear what you're asking with the rest of the question(s).